# Regex: How to match anything till specific string or end of text

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex that will match anything between a specific string (`#`  in this case) or between this string and the end of the text.

Currently, I have something like that: `/^\# ([\s\S]*)\# /gm` and I'm testing it on such a sample text:

```
# Group 1
## Section 1.1

# Group 2
## Section 2.1

# Group 3
Test
```

It returns one match with such a group inside:

```
Group 1
## Section 1.1

# Group 2
## Section 2.1
```

and should return three matches with these groups:

```
Group 1
## Section 1.1
```

```
Group 2
## Section 2.1
```

```
Group 3
Test
```

Any idea how I can achieve that?

Comment: `$` will try to matches the end of a string, or end of the line if you use multiline mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a positive lookahead is supported, tou could repeat matching all lines that do not start with `#`

```
^# (.*(?:\r?\n(?!# ).*)*)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `#`  Match `#` and a space
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `.*` Match the rest of the line
  - `(?:\r?\n(?!# ).*)*` Match a newline and all lines that do not start with `#`
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bpyt0j/1)

Getting the value from group 1 for example with JavaScript

```js
const regex = /^# (.*(?:\r?\n(?!# ).*)*)/gm;
const str = `# Group 1
## Section 1.1

# Group 2
## Section 2.1

# Group 3
Test`;
console.log(Array.from(str.matchAll(regex), m => m[1]));
```